# Android tic tac toe game - logic issue

Tags: android

I'm making 'Tic Tac Toe' game. 3x3 fields, basic. Now I made some of the logic, plus for random computer
choice. But it happens sometime when I click on the field, the computer doesn't make it's move. I think
the problem is in the arraylist. Check out my xml and java files:

MY XML FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.tictactoe.ThirdActivity"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/buttonColor"
            android:onClick="onClickButton"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text=" "/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.00"
            android:background="@color/buttonColor"
            android:onClick="onClickButton"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text=" "/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonThree"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/buttonColor"
            android:onClick="onClickButton"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text=" "/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
        android:layout_weight="4">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonFour"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/buttonColor"
            android:onClick="onClickButton"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text=" "/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonFive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/buttonColor"
            android:onClick="onClickButton"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text=" "/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSix"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/buttonColor"
            android:onClick="onClickButton"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text=" "/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thirdLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSeven"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/buttonColor"
            android:onClick="onClickButton"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text=" "/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonEight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/buttonColor"
            android:onClick="onClickButton"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text=" "/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonNine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/buttonColor"
            android:onClick="onClickButton"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text=" "/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fourthLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/restart"
            android:textColor="@color/text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MY JAVA FILE:

```
package com.tictactoe;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class ThirdActivity extends Activity {

    Button buttonOne;
    Button buttonTwo;
    Button buttonThree;
    Button buttonFour;
    Button buttonFive;
    Button buttonSix;
    Button buttonSeven;
    Button buttonEight;
    Button buttonNine;
    ArrayList<Button> myList = new ArrayList<Button>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
        actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.tictactoe);
        actionBar.setTitle("Play Game");

        buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOne);
        buttonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTwo);
        buttonThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonThree);
        buttonFour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFour);
        buttonFive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFive);
        buttonSix = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSix);
        buttonSeven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSeven);
        buttonEight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEight);
        buttonNine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNine);


        myList.add(0, buttonOne);
        myList.add(1, buttonTwo);
        myList.add(2, buttonThree);
        myList.add(3, buttonFour);
        myList.add(4, buttonFive);
        myList.add(5, buttonSix);
        myList.add(5, buttonSeven);
        myList.add(5, buttonEight);
        myList.add(5, buttonNine);

    }


    public void onClickButton(View view) {
        if (view.equals(buttonOne)) {
            CharSequence textOne = buttonOne.getText().toString();
            if (!textOne.equals(" ")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This filed is not empty, choose another.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                buttonOne.setText("X");
                buttonOne.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                myList.remove(buttonOne);

                Button random = myList.get(new Random().nextInt(myList.size()));
                if (!random.equals(" ")) {
                    random.setText("O");
                    random.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }



        } else if (view.equals(buttonTwo)) {
            CharSequence textTwo = buttonTwo.getText().toString();
            if (!textTwo.equals(" ")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This filed is not empty, choose another.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                buttonTwo.setText("X");
                buttonTwo.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                myList.remove(buttonTwo);

                Button random = myList.get(new Random().nextInt(myList.size()));
                if (!random.equals(" ")) {
                    random.setText("O");
                    random.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }



        } else if (view.equals(buttonThree)) {
            CharSequence textThree = buttonThree.getText().toString();
            if (!textThree.equals(" ")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This filed is not empty, choose another.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                buttonThree.setText("X");
                buttonThree.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                myList.remove(buttonThree);

                Button random = myList.get(new Random().nextInt(myList.size()));
                if (!random.equals(" ")) {
                    random.setText("O");
                    random.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }



        } else if (view.equals(buttonFour)) {
            CharSequence textFour = buttonFour.getText().toString();
            if (!textFour.equals(" ")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This filed is not empty, choose another.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                buttonFour.setText("X");
                buttonFour.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                myList.remove(buttonFour);

                Button random = myList.get(new Random().nextInt(myList.size()));
                if (!random.equals(" ")) {
                    random.setText("O");
                    random.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }



        } else if (view.equals(buttonFive)) {
            CharSequence textFive = buttonFive.getText().toString();
            if (!textFive.equals(" ")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This filed is not empty, choose another.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                buttonFive.setText("X");
                buttonFive.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                myList.remove(buttonFive);

                Button random = myList.get(new Random().nextInt(myList.size()));
                if (!random.equals(" ")) {
                    random.setText("O");
                    random.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }



        }else if (view.equals(buttonSix)) {
            CharSequence textSix = buttonSix.getText().toString();
            if (!textSix.equals(" ")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This filed is not empty, choose another.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                buttonSix.setText("X");
                buttonSix.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                myList.remove(buttonSix);

                Button random = myList.get(new Random().nextInt(myList.size()));
                if (!random.equals(" ")) {
                    random.setText("O");
                    random.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        }else if (view.equals(buttonSeven)) {
            CharSequence textSeven = buttonSeven.getText().toString();
            if (!textSeven.equals(" ")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This filed is not empty, choose another.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                buttonSeven.setText("X");
                buttonSeven.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                myList.remove(buttonSeven);

                Button random = myList.get(new Random().nextInt(myList.size()));
                if (!random.equals(" ")) {
                    random.setText("O");
                    random.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        }else if (view.equals(buttonEight)) {
            CharSequence textEight = buttonEight.getText().toString();
            if (!textEight.equals(" ")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This filed is not empty, choose another.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                buttonEight.setText("X");
                buttonEight.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                myList.remove(buttonEight);

                Button random = myList.get(new Random().nextInt(myList.size()));
                if (!random.equals(" ")) {
                    random.setText("O");
                    random.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        }else if (view.equals(buttonNine)) {
            CharSequence textNine = buttonNine.getText().toString();
            if (!textNine.equals(" ")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This filed is not empty, choose another.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                buttonNine.setText("X");
                buttonNine.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                myList.remove(buttonNine);

                Button random = myList.get(new Random().nextInt(myList.size()));
                if (!random.equals(" ")) {
                    random.setText("O");
                    random.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, that this fragment of code makes problem:

```
        Button random = myList.get(new Random().nextInt(myList.size()));
        if (!random.equals(" ")) {
            random.setText("O");
            random.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
```

For example: Player chooses first button, then it's time for computer to choose, computer as a random chooses 0, but this button was already clicked by player, so nothing is happening

You should make some function like this to make sure that computer will choose correct number.

```
private void computerMove(){
    Button random = myList.get(new Random().nextInt(myList.size()));
    if (!random.equals(" ")) {
        random.setText("O");
        random.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    } else {
        computerMove();
    }
}
```

It's not perfect solution, it could freeze app, you should think about better aproache of choosing field by computer.

**EDIT**
I see another problem, look at this:

```
myList.add(0, buttonOne);
myList.add(1, buttonTwo);
myList.add(2, buttonThree);
myList.add(3, buttonFour);
myList.add(4, buttonFive);
myList.add(5, buttonSix);
myList.add(5, buttonSeven);
myList.add(5, buttonEight);
myList.add(5, buttonNine);
```

You are adding buttons to the same position, position 5.

Also I refactored a little bit your function, becouse there is a lot of boilerpalte:

```
public void onClickButton(View view) {
    if (view instanceof Button){
        Button btn = (Button) view;
        CharSequence text = btn.getText();
        if(!text.equals(" ")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "This filed is not empty, choose another.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            btn.setText("X");
            btn.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            myList.remove(btn);
            computerMove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I somehow add after: 
Button random = myList.get(new Random().nextInt(myList.size()));
                if (!random.equals(" ")) {
                    random.setText("O");
                    random.setTextColor(Color.RED);

a code else if random equals to X or O then pick another random number?

Comment: Anyway, what's better approach? Thank you for your time my friend.

Comment: You can do it, but what when the second random number is also occupied by X or O? That's why it is better to make some iteration to find free field and put O in here.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a solution to the problem you stated but I don't think you can use `.equals()` to compare a button and a string as you did here...
`!random.equals(" ")`. 
Why not repeat what you did here?

```
CharSequence textTwo = buttonTwo.getText().toString();
```